# Magento 2 - Add Attribute to Customer

Tags: magento2, attributes, customer

I want to add a custom attribute to customer using the following piece of code. 
The file is located at `vendor/module/Setup/InstallData.php`. I run `magento setup:upgrade` successfully. But the new attribute does not show in admin. What's wrong with it?

```
<?php

namespace vendor\module\Setup
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface {

    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory, Config $eavConfig) {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'sample_attribute', [
            'type' => 'int',
            'label' => 'Sample Attribute',
            'input' => 'select',
            'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
            'required' => true,
            'default' => '0',
            'sort_order' => 100,
            'system' => false,
            'position' => 100
                ]
        );
        $sampleAttribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'sample_attribute');
        $sampleAttribute->setData(
                'used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer_address', 'customer_address_edit', 'customer_register_address']
        );
        $sampleAttribute->save();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**module.xml,**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
   <module name="Customer_Attrib"  setup_version="1.0.0">
       <sequence>           
            <!--<module name="Customer_Attrib"/>-->
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        </sequence>   
   </module>
</config>
```

It seems CustomerSetupFactory and Model is missing. Please use below script for the same. 
**InstallData.php**

```
<?php 
namespace Customer\Attrib\Setup;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;



/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
                $setup->startSetup();


        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'my_measurements', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Mymeasurements',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 1000,
            'position' => 1000,
            'system' => 0,
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'my_measurements')
        ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['customer_address_edit'],
        ]);

        $attribute->save();

                $setup->endSetup();



    }
}
```

Now run commands,

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/ var/cache/ var/page_cache/ var/generation/
rm -rf  pub/static/frontend/
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:flush 
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

**Now login to the admin your attribute will be displayed in the customer section as per the below screen shot.**

[image]

Comment: Can you PLEASE let me know how can i add more than 1 attribute?

Comment: the question it is a boolean and it is answering with a text