# Magento 2 : Uncaught Error: Call to a member function create() on null in UpgradeSchema

Tags: magento2, customer

I am adding customer attribute,

but getting this error after running

setup:upgrade command, for UpgradeSchema

```
    PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function create() on null in /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Neo/Authorizerobin/Setup/UpgradeSchema.php:47
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/magento2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(832): Neo\Authorizerobin\Setup\UpgradeSchema->upgrade(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\Setup), Object(Magento\Setup\Model\ModuleContext))
#1 /var/www/html/magento2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(779): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->handleDBSchemaData(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\Setup), 'schema')
#2 /var/www/html/magento2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/UpgradeCommand.php(73): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installSchema()
#3 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php(257): Magento\Setup\Console\Command\UpgradeCommand->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#4 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(874):  in /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Neo/Authorizerobin/Setup/UpgradeSchema.php on line 47
```

My UpgradeSchema.php,

```
<?php

namespace Neo\Authorizerobin\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $_customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set
     */
    protected $_attributeSet;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\attribute\SetFactory
     */
    protected $_attributeSetFactory; 

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeRepositryInterface
     */
    protected $_attributeRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set $attributeSet,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\attribute\SetFactory $attributeSetFactory,
        \Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeRepositoryInterface $attributeRepository)
    {
        $_customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $_attributeSet = $attributeSet;
        $_attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
        $_attributeRepository = $attributeRepository;
    }

    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $customerSetup = $this->_customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

         $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

         /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->_attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $_attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        if ($customerSetup->getAttributeId('customer', 'authnetcim_profile_id') === false) {
            $customerSetup->addAttribute(
                Customer::ENTITY,
                'auth_account_number',
                [
                    'label'            => 'Authorize account number to be used for payment',
                    'type'             => 'varchar',
                    'input'            => 'text',
                    'default'          => '',
                    'position'         => 70,
                    'visible'          => true,
                    'required'         => false,
                    'system'           => false,
                    'user_defined'     => true,
                    'visible_on_front' => false,
                ]
            );

            $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'auth_account_number')
        ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],
        ]);

            $attribute->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is problem in following line.

```
 \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\attribute\SetFactory $attributeSetFactory
```

Update it to as follows

```
 \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory $attributeSetFactory
```

Comment: Oh that was too silly mistake ! ++1 for it, but still same issue is coming Kishan

Comment: Please compare with or follow  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128167/magento-2-add-attribute-to-customer/128169

Comment: Okay @Kishan I will check with that